# trying to scrape a webpage in python, and not getting what I need. Getting a index out of range error

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I am trying to just scrape the jackpot amount for the mega millions. I have done an excel sheet that I have to update manually, and was just looking for a way to have python get the jackpot amount for me.

I am using the https://lottery.sd.gov/game/mega-millions/ website, mainly because they print out the numbers and not spell out the amount.

```
jackpot_element = html.xpath("/html/body/div/main/div/section[1]/div/div[2]")[0]

# Extract the jackpot amount from the element
jackpot_amount = jackpot_element.text

print(jackpot_amount)
```

I am using the lxml library and I recive an error

> File "C:mainPlan.py", line 162, in get_jackpot_amount
>
> jackpot_element =
> html.xpath("/html/body/div/main/div/section[1]/div/div[2]")[0]
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
> IndexError: list index out of range

I don't know what I'm doing in the first place and don't know were to go from here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are you using to read the site?  The page is built dynamically with Javascript.  If you are using `requests`, then the numbers are not present in the HTML.

Comment: Check the output of `html.xpath("/html/body/div/main/div/section[1]/div/div[2]")`, does it have at least one element?

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to use API call to get jackpot amount for the mega millions:

```
import requests
jackpot = requests.get('https://lottery.sd.gov/api/igt/v2/draw-games/draws/?game-names=Mega%20Millions').json()['draws'][0]['estimatedJackpot']
print(jackpot)
```

Output:

```
110000000000
```

Comment: effing sweet, how do you get the api? but that worked great.

Comment: I would like to do it for the other lotteries as well, is why I ask.

Comment: and that makes it 110 billion how would we get the correct amount of 1.1 billion?

Comment: I just devided by 100 to get the 1.1billion

Comment: I think this amount  in cents, not in dollars. So, yes, you need to divide it to 100.

Comment: Press F12 if you're in Chrome browser to open Developers Console to see all the APIs.

Comment: what to you look for in the Developer Console? I don't see anything obvious?

Comment: Open `Network` tab and check list of requests: https://i.paste.pics/5f391a1ba2febd0a7a66d6bb9627ccbd.png